# How enable the connection logging for IE11 and Edge?

Tags: debugging, logging, browser

how can I enable the connection logging for IE11 and Egde? And where should I find the generated file? For chrome, it's enough run the browser with the command `--enable-logging --v=1`. This produces the file `chrome_debug.log` in the directory  `AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data` of my user. I have to do manual debugging of the http connection. I'm on Windows.